# SQL Server: Datagridview display column value from table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I want to display in datagridview a specified column value. Example: from table `user_account` I want to display and search by textbox data from column `account` in datagridview

Here is the code so far:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + textBox1.Text + ";" + "User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";" + "Password=" + textBox3.Text;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM user_account";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) ;
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "account");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "account";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + textBox1.Text + ";" + "User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";" + "Password=" + textBox3.Text;
        string sql = "SELECT account FROM user_account";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) ;
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "account");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

    }
```

Comment: give break points and check step by step..then you will know where you are lacking

Comment: With dataGridView1.DataMember = "account"; shows all table but not what i want.

Comment: if you want to filter values with textbox.text,then use SELECT * FROM user_account where account=" + textBox.Text + ";...this only will filter..But you have done code to diaply all..

Comment: for textbox i got answay down. Beside I can't give break piont because it returns no error.

Comment: use this...SELECT * FROM user_account where account=" + textBox.Text + ";

Comment: It returns invalid column name.

Comment: I want to search in textbox7 for a name that is located in column "account" . Column account is second column in database.

Comment: so here the code...SELECT account FROM user_account where account='" + textBox7.Text + "';replace what i gave with this "string sql = "SELECT * FROM user_account";"

Comment: Like this?  string sql = "SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE account=" + textBox7.Text; because this not work.

Comment: not that...SELECT account FROM user_account WHERE account='" + textBox7.Text +"';

Comment: Returns: Invalid column name 'test'

Comment: Managed with: string sql = "SELECT account ,pay_stat FROM user_account where account='" + textBox7.Text + "' ";
          But it dose not let me modify value from column in database?

Comment: For example. How can I update column pay_stat by account name?

Comment: Update user_account set pay_stat = '"+some value+"' where accountname='"+ some other value+"';

Comment: I made this. But not work:  string sql = "UPDATE user_account SET pay_stat='" + textBox8.Text + "'WHERE account='" + textBox9.Text + "' ";

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2db" + ";" + "User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";" + "Password=" + textBox3.Text;
        string sql = "SELECT account ,pay_stat FROM user_account where account='" + textBox7.Text + "' ";          
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) ;
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "pay_stat");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "pay_stat";


    }
```

Thank you for help.