# How to display datagridview rows and items in designtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I would like to display DataGridView rows during designmode/designtime. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried using this function: `datagridview1.Rows.Add();` in the control's constructor but the rows and their items are displayed only in *runtime*.

The reason why i need to display rows and their items in *designtime* is that i am customizing the appearance of the *datagridview control*. So each time i make changes like changing the *AlternatingRowColor, RowFont, etc* i will have to run the control to see the changes.

This eats up time.

If i could display all the rows in *designtime/designmode* then i would be able to see changes immediately as i make them which will save much time.

I am customizing the appearance of the *Datagridview Control* in *Windows Forms* and I'm using *C#*.

I am not defining the control in code but rather have *dragged-n-dropped* the control from the Controls Tab and onto a Winform.

Thanks.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627873/sql-server-datagridview-display-column-value-from-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add a [designer verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to the context menu of the `DataGridView` and assign it by desired behavior. For example (as a start point to preview with dummy data):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    private IDesignerHost designerHost;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (DesignMode && Site != null)
        {
            designerHost = Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            var designer = (ControlDesigner)designerHost?.GetDesigner(this);
            designer?.Verbs?.Add(new DesignerVerb("Preview with dummy data", (o, a) =>
            {
                //Some logic to add dummy rows, just for example
                this.Rows.Clear();
                if (Columns.Count > 0)
                {
                    var values = Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                        .Select(x => GetDummyData(x)).ToArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                        Rows.Add(values);
                }
            }));
            designer?.Verbs?.Add(new DesignerVerb("Clear data", (o, a) =>
            {
                this.Rows.Clear();
            }));
        }
    }
    private object GetDummyData(DataGridViewColumn column)
    {
        //You can put some logic to generate dummy data based on column type, etc.
        return "Sample";
    }
}
```

Then as a result, you will see two menu items added to the context menu and by clicking on "Preview with dummy data", you will see two dummy rows added to the control at design time:

[image]

Comment: Aghael: I will try the solution you presented. When i was reading your code it made sense

Comment: No problem, the screenshot has taken from the same `MyDataGridView` class at design-time. By the way, you can call me Reza. In fact Aghaei is my last name ;)

Comment: I have tried your solution and it addresses exactly my problem. I really appreciate. Now i can customize the DataGridView without having to run it each time.

Comment: Cool! That's great! Its good enough to start. You can enhance the logic of generating dummy data later.

Comment: This solution will help many who desire to customize the DataGridView control in designmode. That's great!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible in WinForms DataGridView, only in WPF. Maybe you can achieve this by extending it somehow, but it's probably not easy and doesn't worth it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bc6c84c1-0a3a-4c97-8966-30be371576d9/how-to-add-some-row-to-datagridview-control-at-design-time?forum=winforms

> Adding rows to the DataGridView in design time is not supported. Based on my understanding, this is because we often bind a data source to the DataGridView to generate rows, not add them directly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the answer of Alex P., it is not possible. With a bit of experience, you'll be able to foretell the appearance.

If you have a lot of visual designing (i.e. due to your customer's detailed requirements), you can also design a little ***test application***, where you can have i.e. a color list and font picker and apply selected properties to the `DataGridView` properties like `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`, `.ForeColor`, `Font`, etc. at runtime. Simply using button or `.SelectionChanged` event for each property. You could probably find something finished on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/) or [Github](http://github.com) ([this is related](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control.md)).